# Browser Intent with User-Agent

Tags: android, user-agent, android-browser, http-request

I'm trying to open the Android browser through a Intent with a custom User-Agent (cause the client website redirects to the mobile page) as far as I got is:

```
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.clientwebsite.com"));
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("User-Agent", "desktop");
            i.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_HEADERS, bundle);
            startActivity(i);
```

But this is still being redirected to Mobile page.

What is a valid User-Agent to identify a not-mobile user?
Setting User-Agent on EXTRA_HEADERS of the Intent really modify this header or it's overridden by the Browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I solved creating my own WebActivity with the User-Agent as 'desktop'.

```
    web.getSettings().setUserAgentString("desktop");
```

Answer (score 1):

The browser does not allow individual tabs to have a different User Agent and the setting is private to the browser.

Comment: =/ Can I change it using a WebView?